# defining a built in type on heap

Tags: c++, heap-memory, built-in

I declared an integer array on heap like this

```
int* a = new int[100];
```

and then I initialized it like this

```
for(int i=0; i<100; i++)
    a[i] = i;
```

which worked perfectly but then I tried this

```
for(int i=0; i<1000; i++)
    a[i] = i;
```

which also worked perfectly.Since I am a newbie to c++ can anyone explain what's the problem in this above declaration because I think the declaration of integer array is not proper or might be anything else?

Comment: array in c++ doesnot have a check for bounds

Comment: The is no boundary check in c++, and the results after 100 is undefined.

Comment: it _seemed_ to work perfectly, but consider yourself _unlucky_ that you did not get a segmantation fault in second case.

Comment: I was hoping to get a segmentation fault which I didn't. can I impose these restrictions on built in types

Comment: *it seemed to work perfectly* in more complex program will fail.

Comment: Try to use `vector` instead if you are going to use C++. Using `.at` instead of `[]` will check the boundary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you write past the end of an array you get undefined behaviour. The important word is *undefined*. It may depend on the compiler, the environment, the compiler flags, ...

In you example it worked because you wrote on a memory that is accessible, but you could (non limitative list) :

- try to access unavailable memory and get a segmentation violation
- try to write read only memory
- ovewrite other variable belonging to your own code
- erase your own stack

But as it is *undefined behaviour* nothing guarantees that this happens. You only know you must **never** do that.

With recent (decent OS) you cannot crash the system, but only your own application except if you run with admin or root privileges, in what case anything can happen. But with older systems like MS/DOS (or some embedded system) there are no inter application protection and system crash are likely to happen with such program.

Comment: Can it cause windows or linux crash?

Comment: when does a compiler shows segmentation fault behaviour

Comment: @saurabh : with recent OS, you do not directly access real memory addresses, but the system maps *segments* (ie consecutive zones) of memory in the process address space. You get a segmentation fault (at runtime the compiler is no longer involved) when you try to access a non mapped address.

Comment: could you please elaborate a non mapped address

Answer (score 1):

You have created an array of `100 ints` on heap. But you are accessing memory much beyond that. C++ doesn't stop you from doing that, but it's an undefined behavior i.e you could get a crash, corrupt memory used by some other program etc.

Answer (score 0):

You declared the variable with 100. But you are assigning the value up to 1000.

```
int* a = new int[100];
```

make that as 1000.

Edit:

If you are accessing the memory that is not declared for that variable it will be segmentation fault. Some of the times only it will work correctly.

Comment: ok fine, but can you explain a bit regarding the mistake?

Comment: This is not the question!

Comment: sorry for the mistake.

Answer (score 0):

you just assigning some memory even you dont have permission to that. it can work. but, I am %100 sure, the program itself will break at some point.

Answer (score 0):

C and c++ do not check for that kind of overflow. You are expected to never let that happen. Needless to say, this is 1/2 the reason that C and C++ have a reputation for being unforgiving.

You are lucky the program did not crash out violently. But it will, and very soon with that much smashing of other memory.

Comment: I would say, OP is _unlucky_ that the program din't segfault. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Technically "a" is just a pointer (as you have declared it).

Then you have made it point to the start of some array (on the heap in this case).

Then you are incrementing the pointer and setting the value. The compiler will not have a problem with this at all since "a" is not an array, but a pointer to a bit of memory that the compiler is told is an integer. So you could have your loop go on as long as you want, but it will start to overwrite memory used for other purposes, probably end up with a seg fault somewhere along the way.... or some other strange behavior :o

Comment: but I imposed a restriction on it by saying **new int[100]** so does that mean nothin

Comment: no, "a" is just a "int *". You make it point to the memory address allocated by "new int[100]". You can make "a" point to anywhere in accessible memory, in this case it starts pointing to the start of your array, but by the end you have moved it way beyond this array. This is perfectly legal code as far as the compiler is aware (you may have reasons to do this.... it does not know).